# Have two shield buttons

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Is there a way to configure my controls such that both of my triggers are `Shield`? I have an extra jump button floating around that I would much rather just replace with `Shield`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, the controls configuration requires all of the button actions (Attack, Special, Grab, Shield, and two Jumps) to be mapped to one of the buttons (A, B, L, R, X, Y). There is no mechanism to select the action individually for each button, only to move these preset actions among the buttons (and turn Tap Jump off).